# Проверка ввода scanf

Tags: c

Как можно наиболее эффективно проверить ввод с помощью scanf? Например, `scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);` Как можно тут проверить корректность ввода? Чтобы при вводе, например, символа, выдавало ошибку. Возвращает ли что-то эта функция?

Comment: Реализовать что-то пробовали? Приведите свой код реализации проверки, если возможно.

Comment: Перед тем, как задать вопрос, бывает нелишним прочесть *manpage* (в вашем случае [man 3 scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) и там раздел **Return Value** -- *`"...return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned..."`*)

Answer (score 3):

Функция `scanf` возвращает количество успешно прочитанных значений. В вашем примере, в случае успешного ввода функция `scanf` вернет значение `3`. Соответственно, если первое значение будет прочитано успешно, а при чтении второго произойдет ошибка, то функция `scanf` вернет значение `1`.