# Как проверить тип данных в С?

Tags: c, типы-данных

Например, я забиваю массив элементами типа данных float. Нужно, чтобы соответствовало только float или было автоматическое преобразование данных.
Т.е при вводе с клавиатуры символа char выкидывал на повтор ввода.

```
for (t=0;t<a,++t)
{
 printf("input %i = ",t+1);
 if(scanf("%f",&q)=!1)
 {
   printf("Try again =");
   scanf("%f",&q);
 }
x[t]=q;
}
```

Данное решение не работает.

Comment: У вас ошибка в операторе `if()`. Вместо `=!` должно быть `!=`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка ввода scanf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995659/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-scanf)

Comment: перед повторным `scanf` надо очистить буфер ввода от неправильных букв. например так : `while (getchar() != '\n');`

Comment: а лучше всего сначала ввести строку, а потом её в `sscanf`